# Javascript cloneNode for adding new elements

Tags: javascript

what I'm trying to do is. when I click

```
function runIt(text) { 
  var counter = 1;
  var comment = document.getElementById("name");
  comment.innerText = text;
  comment.cloneNode(true);
  comment.id += counter;
}
document.addEventListener("click", function(e){
    runIt("test")
}, true);
```

I want it to ADD a new element underneath that output "test".
it's keep getting replaced. :(

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>t</title>
</head>
<body>
<p id="name" class="someclass"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: [`comment.cloneNode(true)`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode) _returns_ a new node. You’re not using its result. You only mutate the original element. Nothing else is getting replaced. Familiarize yourself with the [DOM API](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model).

Answer (score 0):

`cloneNode` returns the new code, which you can then [append](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/append) to the DOM. Also counter should be defined outside the function and then incremented each time.

```js
var counter = 1;
function runIt(text) { 
  var comment = document.getElementById("name");
  newcomment = comment.cloneNode(true);
  newcomment.innerText = text;
  newcomment.id += counter;
  counter++;
  document.querySelector('body').append(newcomment)
}
document.addEventListener("click", function(e){
    runIt("test")
}, true);
```

```html
<p id="name" class="someclass">-</p>
```